# Can't access a specific element in a 2D Matrix represented as a List of Lists

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to access a specific element in a 2D Matrix represented as list of Lists so I can set that specific element to 0. However, when I run the code below:

```
(defvar listOfLists '( (1 3) (2 6) ))
(defvar referenceToTopLeftCorner (elt 0 (elt 0 listOfLists)))
(setq referenceToTopLeftCorner 0)
(print (format nil "listsOfLists = ~a" listOfLists))
```

The following output is:

> "- ELT: 0 is not a SEQUENCE"

This seems strange, as I thought that the `ELT` method can be used to get values within a list?

Comment: When an element is of scalar type, `elt` returns its value, not a reference, eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong argument order for [`elt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_elt.htm):

> elt sequence index => object

Comment: I updated my code to use the correct syntax. However, when I run my program, it doesn't seem that the element in the list of lists is changed.

Comment: of course it doesn't. that's a separate error requiring a separate question as per the site's policy. ;-) BTW, you should revert your change to the question. It is wrong to change a question that has been answered so radically.

Comment: I accepted your answer :D. I have a new question that relates to getting the reference of an element in a list of lists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026129/lisp-how-to-get-the-reference-not-the-value-of-an-element-in-a-2d-matrix-repr