# Lisp: How to get the reference (not the value) of an element in a 2D Matrix represented as a List of Lists?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to **reference** a specific element in a 2D Matrix represented as list of Lists so I can set that specific element to 0. However, when I run the code below:

```
(defvar listOfLists '( (1 3) (2 6) ))
(defvar referenceToTopLeftCorner (nth 0 (nth 0 listOfLists)))
(setq referenceToTopLeftCorner 0)
(print (format nil "listsOfLists = ~a" listOfLists))
```

The following output is:

> ""listsOfLists = ((1 3) (2 6))"

This seems strange, as I thought that the `nth` method can be used to get references within a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you called reference is *not* a reference.

You need to do

```lisp
(setf (nth 0 (nth 0 list-of-lists)) 0)
```

Note that you could also do

```lisp
(defvar 1st-list (first list-of-lists))
(setf (first 1st-list) 0)
```

for the same effect, because `1st-list` *refers* to the 1st list in `list-of-lists`.

You could also use [`define-symbol-macro`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defi_1.htm):

```lisp
(define-symbol-macro reference-to-top-left-corner
  (first (first list-of-lists)))
(setf reference-to-top-left-corner 0)
```

because now `reference-to-top-left-corner` really *is* a reference.

I strongly advise you ***not*** to use symbol macros yet.
Such advanced tools should be used sparingly and cautiously.

Answer (score 2):

Lisp doesn't have references in that sense.  Except, of course, that it's Lisp: it has whatever you want it to have.

```
(defmacro locative (form)               ;in memory of Zetalisp
  `(lambda (&optional (value nil valuep))
     (if valuep
         (setf ,form value)
       ,form)))

(defun valof (locative)                 ;in memory of BCPL
  (funcall locative))

(defun (setf valof) (value locative)
  (funcall locative value))
```

And now

```
> (let ((lol (copy-tree '((1 3) (2 6)))))
    (let ((tlc (locative (nth 0 (nth 0 lol)))))
      (print (valof tlc))
      (setf (valof tlc) 8)
      lol))
1
((8 3) (2 6))
```

Comment: Upvoted because I haven't thought about locatives in decades :)

Comment: @Barmar: to be fair I don't think they have much in common with what locatives actually were (although I'm not sure I can remember now).

Comment: Real locatives were pointers that would be automatically updated by the GC when the targeted object was moved -- the basic component of all the reference types (e.g. a cons cell was just a pair of locatives). But in implementations without them, your macro was a common way of emulating them.